# How to get the value from GRID using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

just want to ask if you can help me with my problem,

I have a grid in my form created using JQuery, and I want to get the value inputted by the user on that grid and save it into my DB.

the flow goes like this,

first, they will select the no. of sites (no. of cell to be shade), then they will click the right cell they want. then after that my problem starts, how can I get the value they inputted then save it.

here's the working demo of my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/reymartinaruta/qnm96/

```
var CMAP = function() {

    // animation
    var blink = function(id)
    {
        $(id).animate({opacity: 0.2}, 300).delay(400)
                .animate({opacity: 1}, 300,
                function()
                {
                    blink();
                }
        );
    };

    return {
        //create map function to initiate the module
        initCreateMAP: function()
        {
            var html = '<table>';
            for (i = 0; i < 15; i++)
            {
                html += "<tr>";
                for (j = 0; j < 15; j++)
                {
                    html += '<td><div id="p' + ((i * 15) + j)  + '" class="mappoint" style="width:20px; height:20px;"></div></td>';
                }
                html += "</tr>";
            }

            html += "</table>";            
            $('#layout').html(html);

        },

        // main function to initiate        
        initCMAP: function()
        {            
            var Point = new Array();

            $('#select5').change(function(){
                Point.length =  0;
                $(".mappoint-change").each(function () {
                        $(this).removeClass('mappoint-change');
                        $(this).html('');
                });

                for(i=0; i < parseInt($('#select5').val()); i++) Point.push(i);

            });

              $('.mappoint').click(function() {

                  var text = $(this).text();

                  if(text != '')
                  {
                      Point.unshift(parseInt(text));
                      $(this).html('');
                      $(this).removeClass('mappoint-change');
                  }
                  else
                  {
                        Point.sort(function(a,b){
                            return a-b;
                        });

                        if(Point.length == 0) return false;

                        for(var i in Point)
                        {
                              $(this).addClass('mappoint-change');
                              blink(this);
                              $(this).html(Point[i]);
                              Point.shift();
                              break;
                        }
                  }
              });              

           var data = new Array();
           //var data = [ "p0", "p1", "p2", "p33", "p49", "p65", "p127", "p140", "p141", "p142"];

           $('#submit').click(function() {
//                $.post('cmap.action.php', $('#requestfrm').serialize(),
//                        function(data) {
//                            $('#rq-info').html(data);
//                        }
//                );

//                for(i=0; i<data.length; i++)
//                {
//                    $('#' + data[i]).addClass('mappoint-change');
//                    $('#' + data[i]).html(i);
//                }

                $(".mappoint-change").each(function () {                    
                     data.push(this.id);
                });

            });

            $('#reset-cmap').click(function() {
                if(confirm("Do you want to reset your map?"))
                {    
                    $(".mappoint-change").each(function () {
                        Point.unshift(parseInt($(this).text()));
                        $(this).removeClass('mappoint-change');
                        $(this).html('');
                    });
                }
            });
        }       
    };

}();
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: What do you mean with "the value inputted"? do you mean the coordinates of selected cells?

Comment: exactly sir, how will be able to get the coordiante(s) inputted by the user? i also assigned each cell specific ID.

Comment: why can't you simply get that from your click handler? You don't seem to have any problems assigning the values...put them in an array when you do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code. It reads the ID and convert it to coordinates X and Y

Demo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qnm96/2/)

```
        var pointOrder=$(this).attr("id").replace("p","");
        pointOrder=parseInt(pointOrder);

        var corX=parseInt(pointOrder/15);
        var corY=pointOrder%15;
```

Comment: This is the one that I've been looking for thanks @Dola.
I more thing, is it possible to save it in DB??

Comment: @CheeKeeDee, it's possible to save it in the DB, You will need to make an AJAX request to a server side code (PHP, ASP, ..etc) and send the coordinates as a parameters in the request and save them in the DB along with any other data you want.

Comment: Thanks again. it seems that it is new to me, I need first to study that one. do you have tutorial for that topic @Dola?